# How to change pixels only on part of an img in java

Tags: java

I am working on a picture now and the instruction asks me to change pixels of a portion of a picture. I can change the pixels of the whole picture, but I don't know how to only change a part of the picture and leave the other part unchanged. 
Thanks

```
class Proj02Runner {

private Picture mars = new Picture("Proj02.jpg");
public Picture getPicture(){
return mars;
}

public void run(){


Pixel[] arrayPix = mars.getPixels();
for(Pixel pixel : arrayPix) {
  pixel.setRed(255 - pixel.getRed());
  pixel.setGreen(255 - pixel.getGreen());
  pixel.setBlue(127);
}
mars.explore();
}
}
```

This is the result I want: 
[image: CLICK here to see the result I want]

Comment: What is your existing code? How do you change all pixels of the picture? Do you work with BufferedImage or something else? Please provide some more information so we can help you efficiently.

Comment: does anyone know how to add img to my post? So I can explain my question better. the img tag does not work. Thanks

Comment: There is a Buffered Image import that may be helpful to you, also check out the imports similar to `import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;` and `import javax.imageio.ImageIO;` at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: Thanks I change my browser and it turns out IE works better than Chrome on importing pictures.

Comment: You've got to find out how `Picture.getPixels()` organizes pixels of the original image into a 1-dimensional array (usually, this kind of method returns one row after another, so that position x, y in the image turns out to be positon x*w + y, where w is image width). Since you did not say where your `Picture` class come from (what's the import statement?), nor which part of your image you want to edit (from the picture you attached, I guess its a diagonal, but which one? upper right or bottom left?), we can't go further on helping.